# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value while setting custom FooterCell from xib into tableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xib

> footercell is in  xib

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

   let  footerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FooterCell") as! FooterViewCell
    //headerCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    switch(section)
    {
        case 0:
            footerCell.footerLabel.text = "Asian Ocean"
        case 1:
            footerCell.footerLabel.text = "Europian Ocean"
        case 2:
            footerCell.footerLabel.text = "American Ocean"
        default:
            footerCell.footerLabel.text = "Other"
    }

    return footerCell
    /*return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("FooterViewCell", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as? UIView*/
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 35.0
}
```